# Haskell: Deducing function from type

Tags: haskell, types

So I was playing around with Haskell today, thinking about autogeneration of function definitions given a type.

For example, the definition of the function

```
twoply :: (a -> b, a -> c) -> a -> (b, c)
```

is obvious to me given the type (if I rule out use of `undefined :: a`).

So then I came up with the following:

```
¢ :: a -> (a ->b) -> b
¢ = flip ($)
```

Which has the interesting property that

```
(¢) ¢ ($) :: a -> (a -> b) -> b
```

Which brings me to my question.  Given the relation `=::=` for "has the same type as", does the statement `x =::= x x ($)` uniquely define the type of `x`?  Must `x =::= ¢`, or does there exist another possible type for `x`?

I've tried to work backward from `x =::= x x ($)` to deduce `x :: a -> (a -> b) -> b`, but gotten bogged down.

Comment: sepp2k has answered your question, but it's worth noting that `flip id` is an equivalent definition of your `¢` that makes the reason for the property you note a bit more obvious (to me, at least).

Comment: In other words, at the risk of over-explaining it, `id :: a -> a` specialized to functions is equivalent to `($) :: (a -> b) -> (a -> b)`. Ain't polymorphism great?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`x =::= x x ($)` is also true for `x = const`, which has the type `a -> b -> a`. So it does not uniquely identify the type.

Answer (score 8):

I'd just like add that you should look at http://hackage.haskell.org/package/djinn.  It can take many type signatures and derive an implementation from them.  If there's only one implementation possible for a type that djinn understands, it will produce it.

Answer (score 1):

From the equation above, we can determine some of a type signature for x. X need not have this type, but it needs to at least *unify* with this type.

```
$ :: forall a b. (a -> b) -> a -> b
x :: t1 -> ((a -> b) -> a -> b) -> t1
```

Given that, it should be straightforward to write a multitude of implementations of x.