# Function for given type in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I was wondering if there is any better way for finding FUNCTIONS given only TYPE of it in Haskell. Ex.-

```
Find function for given type- (a->b->c) ?
```

Always I have to think hard in a brute force manner. please help.

I have gone through this - [Haskell: Deducing function from type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3731501/haskell-deducing-function-from-type), but could not find a better way.

Comment: No, I only have type and pen-paper or ghc installed. Now deduce the function

Comment: Are you familiar with [`djinn`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/djinn)? It performs this exact task... and is written in Haskell.

Comment: You can use the same method as djinn does; prove a theorem in intuitionistic propositional logic.

Comment: Actually it can be a type of custom made function. In that case, it won't give me the answer. And I was preparing for some exam thats why I was asking

Comment: The method used by djinn can absolutely be applied to "a type of a custom made function".  That said I'll be quite now that 1) this is clearly off topic for SO 2) the author of Djinn has appeared.

Comment: cheat and use [hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28a-%3Eb-%3Ec%29)

Answer (score 2):

It's sometimes possible. For instance, we all know that there are no "proper" values with type `forall a. a` and only one with type `forall a . a -> a`, but there are an infinite number of ones with type `forall a. (a -> a) -> a -> a`.

In particular, you can think of some Haskell types as expressing theorems in type theory and the process of instantiating them as the process of proving that theorem. There's no general method for doing this, but there are a number of tautological types like `forall a . a -> a` which have easily discoverable proofs.

To learn *much* more about this process, consider reading [Software Foundations](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/sf/) by Benjamin Pierce or [Certified Programming with Dependent Types](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/) by Adam Chlipala. These two both explore how to prove theorems (instantiate types) like this using the language Coq which is similar to Haskell being based on OCaml.

Comment: It's worth noting that your original function, `a -> b -> c` is impossible to construct without "cheating" (using `undefined` or similar). Trivial proof: If it existed suppose it was called `foo`. Then `(foo :: () -> () -> a) () () :: a` which means we can create any type. This also means we can prove types that are logically falsy like `Void`.

Comment: To reinforce this from the logical point of view, the function with type `(a -> b)` cannot exist without cheating already. The type reads, as a logical statement, that "If A then B" for all "A" and "B". "If it is snowing outside, then 2+2=5", "If the sky is blue, then I can fly", and so on. Compare that with the trivial type `forall a . a -> a` which is "proven" by `id :: forall a . a -> a`. As logic that says "If A, then A" for all "A"... which actually makes sense. "If pigs can fly, then pigs can fly", "If I can go faster than the speed of light, then I can go faster than the speed of light"

Answer (score 1):

Besides DJINN (which is an external tool), you can also use the following code

http://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/types.html#de-typechecker

to, informally, convert a type into a value, within Haskell. You can immediately invoke this function.

Answer (score 0):

I guess `.. (\x y -> (x,y) )` can fit into the type `(a->b->c)`

Comment: I believe you misunderstand the question.  The question is more of "give me a function that can be given this type signature".  I can use a function typed `a -> b -> c` in a case demanding `Int -> Float -> Double`, but I can't use your function in that case.

Comment: I get it.. So the function with the signature a->b->c can be (\x y -> undefined)